# Running an event within text box after entering password

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am trying to enter the password into the password field for HTML code below:

```
<input name="customerPassword" type="password" class="customer-password form-control ng-dirty ng-valid-required filled ng-valid ng-valid-minlength" ng-class="{
  'input-error': submitted &amp;&amp; securityForm.customerPassword.$invalid,
  'filled': securityForm.customerPassword.$viewValue.length>0}" ng-minlength="7" maxlength="20" ng-model="customer.password" ng-keydown="checkEnterKey(event)" required="" autocomplete="new-password" aria-autocomplete="list">
<b class="into-input">Password</b>
<div class="ct-icon ng-hide" ng-show="securityForm.$invalid">
            <div class="ct-tooltip">
                <i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-lg info"></i>
                <div class="tooltip">
                    <div class=""><p>This is the password you created when you registered for Internet Banking.&nbsp;</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<met-tooltip category="login" key="input-password" ng-show="securityForm.$valid" icon="check" class="valid-number met-tooltip-bg-green ng-isolate-scope"><span>    <!-- ngIf: !tooltip.inline --><a ng-if="!tooltip.inline" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1" tooltip-trigger="" tooltip-placement="" tooltip-html-unsafe="<p><span style=&quot;line-height:20.8px&quot;>Password entered.</span></p>
" tooltip-popup-delay="100" class="ng-scope">        <i data-ng-click="goTo()" class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>    </a><!-- end ngIf: !tooltip.inline -->    <!-- ngIf: tooltip.inline --></span></met-tooltip>
<a ng-if="!tooltip.inline" href="javascript:void(0)" tabindex="-1" tooltip-trigger="" tooltip-placement="" tooltip-html-unsafe="<p><span style=&quot;line-height:20.8px&quot;>Password entered.</span></p>
" tooltip-popup-delay="100" class="ng-scope">        <i data-ng-click="goTo()" class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>    </a>
```

See below my VBA code snippet:

```
  Dim event_onChange As Object
  Set event_onChange = ie.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    event_onChange.initEvent "keydown", True, False
   .document.querySelector(".customer-password").dispatchEvent event_onChange
```

There is a little circle that appears when i enter the password manually, but it does not appear after I run above VBA code. How is it possible to make that happen with VBA?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58826566/6241235 and use _keydown_ event and target querySelector(".customer-password") node

Comment: sorry, is this what you meant @QHarr?  unfortunately does not work.    Set event_onChange = ie.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");  event_onChange.initEvent "keydown", True, False; .document.querySelector(".customer-password").dispatchEvent event_onChange